# Can schizoaffective disorder be present with no negative symptomatology

Tags: personality-disorder, schizophrenia

In addition to delusions and hallucinations, schizoaffective disorder involves mood alterations.

Is the presence of negative symptomatology necessary for diagnosing schizoaffective disorder, or is mood alteration sufficient if delusions are present?

Comment: I'm afraid something got lost in translation here. What do you mean by: "Can X course with Y ..."? I can't make sense of this sentence/question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the DSM-5, negative symptoms is not a diagnostic requisite for schizoaffective disorder. Negative symptomology is included as a specifier only if the patient presents with these symptoms.
Further, it is important to note that delusions and mood alterations are not the only diagnostic criteria for this disorder. Patients must meet Criterion A for Schizophrenia that occurs concurrently with a major mood episode (must include depressive and may or may not include manic); and at least 2 weeks of delusions or hallucinations without the presence of a mood episode. Also, symptomatic etiology must not be the result of a substance-induced disorder.
Regarding specifiers, clients may present with either Biopolar or depressive type, and may include catatonia. Negative symptoms are remarked in the "Severity specifier" section if present and its severity is rated on a scale of 0 - 4.